# Free for commercial use google-maps equivalent to do the following?

Tags: google-maps, mapping, geolocation

I'm looking for a mapping API something which has similar functionality to Google-maps but which perhaps has something along the lines of the Apache / MIT license. I basically want to plot points on the map. Does such a thing exist? If so are there any guides to plotting points on this map API?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[OpenStreetMap](http://www.openstreetmap.org/) (Their [Wiki](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Main_Page))

Comment: It doesn't even know the name of my street. Pass.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.maptools.org/